# Optimal way to extract "positive part" of a multivariate polynomial

Tags: performance-tuning, polynomials, algebraic-manipulation

I've got multivariate polynomials with numerical coefficients, like e. g.

```
p - s - p q^2 s^2 + 3 r s^2 + 3 r^2 s^2 - p r^2 s^2 - 2 q r^2 s^2 - 2 r^3 s^2 + s^3
```

and I would like to take the sum of those monomials with positive coefficients only.

Although for my purposes

```
FromCoefficientRules[Select[CoefficientRules[poly],Last[#]>0&],Variables[poly]]
```

seems to be quick enough, it involves translating to another form and back, so I feel there must be a more optimal way to do it, probably using some tricks with the internal representation of polynomials.

Is there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will delete the terms written with a leading minus sign:

```
nixneg[p_Plus] := DeleteCases[p, _?Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ];
nixneg[_?Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ] := 0;  (* 1-term case: neg *)
nixneg[p_] := p;                             (* 1-term case: nonneg *)
```

OP's example:

```
nixneg[poly]  (* use nixneg[Expand@poly] if needed *)
(*  p + 3 r s^2 + 3 r^2 s^2 + s^3  *)
```

Deletes negative constant terms, too:

```
nixneg[poly + 100]
nixneg[poly - 100]
(*
  100 + p + 3 r s^2 + 3 r^2 s^2 + s^3
  p + 3 r s^2 + 3 r^2 s^2 + s^3
*)
```

Answer (score 6):

Assuming `poly` is homogeneous (as in the example in the OP),

```
poly /. Times[_?Negative, _] -> 0
```

Comment: Nice! But you mean without constant term rather than homogeneous, right? My polynomials might have constant terms, actually, but I am sure one can deal with them very quickly too

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე oh, yes, I meant without constant term!

Comment: Sorry! - have to accept the most complete one

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე no need to apologise, those are great answers too, clearly better than mine :-)

Answer (score 4):

```
exp = p - s - p q^2 s^2 + 3 r s^2 + 3 r^2 s^2 - p r^2 s^2 - 2 q r^2 s^2 - 2 r^3 s^2 + s^3
```

Few additional ways to use `` Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ ``:

```
Select[Not @* Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ] @ exp
```

> p + 3 r s^2 + 3 r^2 s^2 + s^3

Comment: Thank you! I accepted another one only because it also takes into account constant polynomials too.